# What is the leaf-score in LightGBM (classification)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, loss-function, lightgbm

I have trained LightGBM on a binary-classification problem, and when plotting the tree I get some leafs like  this
[image: This]

I struggle to find the loss-function for the classification trees - Does LightGBM minimize the cross-entropy in the binary case, and is that the leaf score?

Answer (score 0):

> I struggle to find the loss-function for the classification trees - Does LightGBM minimize the cross-entropy in the binary case

Yes, if you don't specify an objective then `LGBMClassifier` will use cross-entropy by default. The documentation in https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier says that the default for `objective` is `"binary"`, and then https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#objective notes that `binary` is cross-entropy loss.

> and is that the leaf score?

The values like `leaf 33: -2.209` ("leaf scores") represent the value of the target that will be predicted for instances in that leaf node, [multiplied by the learning rate](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2755#issuecomment-584977918).

Negative values are possible because of the way the boosting process works. Each tree is trained on the residuals of the model up to that tree. A prediction from a model is obtained by summing the output of all trees. The XGBoost docs have a very good explanation of this: ["Introduction to Boosted Trees"](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html).

In the future, please try to provide a small reproducible example explaining how you created a figure that you're asking questions about. I assumed something like the following Python code, using `lightgbm` 3.1.0. You can change the values of `tree_index` to see the different trees in the model.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

gbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    n_estimators=10,
    num_leaves=3,
    max_depth=8,
    min_data_in_leaf=3,
)

gbm.fit(X, y)

# visualize tree structure as a directed graph
ax = lgb.plot_tree(
    gbm,
    tree_index=0,
    figsize=(15, 8),
    show_info=[
        'data_percentage',
    ]
)

# visualize tree structure in a dataframe
gbm.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```

Comment: What my question regarding the leaf-score is (I should maybe have wrote that more clearly) was; is that the log-odds ratio or ..?

Comment: Since it performs a logistic-regression I assume that it models: log(p(c1)/p(c2))= T0+T1+T2+T3..+TK where Ti is the output from the i'th tree i.e the leaf-score in the i'th tree